# Proving elements of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For the first case of the proof, is that considered to be a valid proof? And, for the second case, I am really stuck and I have no idea what to do. Any hints or tips?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think that if you do it by contradiction it might be easier and shorter, for both ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the $\impliedby$ direction, it's fine except at the last step. Saying that "$\mathbb Z = \mathbb Z + \mathbb Q$ leads to a contradiction" makes me feel uncomfortable. Instead do something like this:

> Since:
>   \begin{align*}
> 4y = 4m + 2
> \implies 2y = 2m + 1 
> \implies 1 = 2y - 2m = 2(\underbrace{y - m}_{\in ~ \mathbb Z})
> \end{align*}
>   it follows that $1$ is even, a contradiction.

---

For the $\implies$ direction, use a similar argument by contradiction:

> Since $2 \mid n$, we know that there is some $k \in \mathbb Z$ such that $n = 2k$. We claim that $k$ is odd.
>
> Otherwise, suppose instead that $k$ was actually even so that $k = 2z$ for some $z \in \mathbb Z$. Then $n = 2(2z) = 4z$. So $4 \mid n$, a contradiction.

Comment: cool! thanks a lot mann!